# Link multiple table field to the same foreign key in TSQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, database-design, foreign-keys, primary-key

I do not really know whether this is logically feasible but I have a table:

```
PERSON: Id (PK), Name, SoldTo (FK), ShipTo (FK), BillTo (FK)

ADDRESS: AddrId (PK), Street, Number, Town, Type
```

`Type` in `ADDRESS` will contain a string describing the address type. I would like to link `SoldTo, ShipTo` and `BillTo` to `AddrId`. Of course they can also point at the same record.

However in SSMS it forbids me to do that.

Anybody knows a workaround or a better way to do it? Thanks

**UPDATE**

In order to see what I mean with *"SSMS forbids me to do that"* have a look at the screenshot in the link below. Consider `CMF_ContactInfo` as `ADDRESS` and `CMF_AccountInfo` as `PERSON`. As you can see I can add `ContactId` to the relationship just once...

[image: SSMS Tables and Columns Dialog]

Comment: Why does *SSMS* forbid you to do this?? Can you show us what you're trying to do (in T-SQL) ?? Do you get errors - if so: **what** errors exactly??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to add multiple relationships ! (with different names) Just like if it were different tables.

Answer (score 4):

Don't know how you are trying to do that in SSMS (possibly you are trying some interactive tools, I know little about them), but this is how you can do what you want in plain Transact-SQL:

```
CREATE TABLE Address (
  AddrId int CONSTRAINT PK_Address PRIMARY KEY,
  Street varchar(50),
  Number int,
  Town varchar(50),
  Type int
);

CREATE TABLE Person (
  Id int PRIMARY KEY,
  Name varchar(100),
  SoldTo int NOT NULL CONSTRAINT FK_Address_SoldTo FOREIGN KEY REFERENCES Address (AddrId),
  ShipTo int NOT NULL CONSTRAINT FK_Address_ShipTo FOREIGN KEY REFERENCES Address (AddrId),
  BillTo int NOT NULL CONSTRAINT FK_Address_BillTo FOREIGN KEY REFERENCES Address (AddrId)
);
```

Not sure about the actual types, but you get the idea. Also you might want to drop `NOT NULL` where it is not needed (or add it where necessary).

Comment: +1 exactly - there should not be any problem creating three FK relations from `Person` to `Address` using those columns....

Comment: +1 to Andriy. My question to @CiccioMiami: It seems like someone is selling, shipping (and billing for) persons. Has slavery been re-legalized in Miami?

Comment: Ahaha, good one! It was just an example. See the screenshot in the question update. Thanks